# jQuery Supersized: Change Thumb Gallery Mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, thumbnails, supersized

I am using the [jQuery Supersized plugin](http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/).

What I'm trying to achieve is to change the effect on `mouseover` of the thumb gallery `ul#thumb-list` with [this effect](http://demo.superdit.com/jquery/zoom_hover/).

To have a clear idea go to [my site](http://www.malvasiaoggianu.it); click `vino > vigna` and click the camera icon:

Anyone help me?

Thanks in advances,
K.

Comment: That plugin is so laggy.

Comment: which version of  jQuery Supersized plugin your are using???????